# Парсинг Html Agility Pack

Tags: html, vb.net

Вот простой код, для получения списка цен на авито

```
html.LoadHtml(Cont)
        Dim node = html.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='items-items-kAJAg']")
        Dim ItemsNode = node.SelectNodes("//div[@class='iva-item-root-_lk9K photo-slider-slider-S15A_ iva-item-list-rfgcH iva-item-redesign-rop6P iva-item-responsive-_lbhG items-item-My3ih items-listItem-Gd1jN js-catalog-item-enum']")
        Dim Price As HtmlNode
        For Each n In ItemsNode

            Dim tmp = n.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='iva-item-titleStep-pdebR']/a").Attributes("href").Value
            MsgBox(tm2p)               
        Next
```

Вместо цены пока вывожу ссылку на объявления. Дело в том, что он в цикле выводит одно и тоже. Ссылки все одинаковые, как и цены. Хотя содержание n различное. Такое ощущение, что идет поиск не в отдельном Node, а в изначальном документе. Почему такое происходит?

Answer (score 0):

> Такое ощущение, что идет поиск не в отдельном Node, а в изначальном документе. Почему такое происходит?

Так и есть, здесь поиск идет в изначальном документе. Тоже сталкивался с такой проблемой. Копаться глубоко не стал, просто поставил точку перед двумя слэшами и заработало. То есть в твоем примере нужно сделать так:

```
Dim tmp = n.SelectSingleNode(".//div[@class='iva-item-titleStep-pdebR']/a").Attributes("href").Value
```

Comment: `//` - Поиск от корня документа. `.` - точка означает текущий узел.